# $A$ Hermitian and $0<P\leq I$ is projector. Is $Tr (PA)\leq Tr(A)$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix and $0<P\leq I$ is a projector matrix. Is this true that we always have: $$Tr (PA)\leq Tr(A)$$
If it is not true in general, what is the condition that makes it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since $P$ is a projection it is diagonal with zeroes and ones on the diagonal with respect to some basis (the minimal polynomial of $P$ must divide $x^2-x = x(x-1)$), say the first $m$ entries are ones and the rest are zeroes. Let $A = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} A_1 & A_2 \\ A_3 & A_4\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ (where $A_1$ is $m\times m$), then by nature of block matrix multiplication $PA = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} A_1 & A_2 \\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, hence $Tr(PA)\leq Tr(A).$